# QR Code from showing whenever expo is running

Tags: expo, metro-bundler

Whenever I ran my react-native app with npm start (using expo btw), I would get a QR code to be able to use the expo app to run the application on my phone.
This code would also be available on the browser expo dev tool. I was using visual code and installed an extension called 'prettier'. After that, every time I ran my application, the terminal output is different and the QR code no longer appears, not even in the browser, there it just stays compiling forever.

*Before:*
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8scA2.jpg

*After:*
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSAe5.jpg

It is now running in 'webpack mode' instead of the 'metro' like it used too, I'm new to expo and app development so don't know how to change it back.